# BIG_ENDIAN code to be fixed for LITTLE_ENDIAN machine as well

Tags: c++, endianness

I have this piece of legacy code which I need to run on both BIG & LITTLE Endian machines. The problem is with hton().

msg->Mac is char Mac[16+1]
**Existing code:(works only on BIG)**

```
if (sscanf(msg->Mac, "%4hx.%4hx.%4hx", (unsigned short *)&new_mac[0],
              (unsigned short *)&new_mac[2],
              (unsigned short *)&new_mac[4]) != 3) {
  return (ERROR_ADDRESS_TRANSLATION);
 }

*(unsigned short *)&new_mac[0] = hton(*(unsigned short *)&new_mac[0]);
*(unsigned short *)&new_mac[2] = hton(*(unsigned short *)&new_mac[2]);
*(unsigned short *)&new_mac[4] = hton(*(unsigned short *)&new_mac[4]);

sprintf((char *)newMac, "%04x.%04x.%04x", *(unsigned short *)&new_mac[0],
        *(unsigned short *)&new_mac[2], *(unsigned short *)&new_mac[4]);

 /* Get the MAC address */
if (sscanf((char *)newMac, "%4hx.%4hx.%4hx", (unsigned short *)&mac_addr[0],
              (unsigned short *)&mac_addr[2],
              (unsigned short *)&mac_addr[4]) != 3) {
      return (ERROR_ADDRESS_TRANSLATION);
 }


 /* Convert to network order */
 *(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[0] = hton(*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[0]);
 *(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[2] = hton(*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[2]);
 *(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[4] = hton(*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[4]);
```

To fix this on LITTLE Endian machine, I am using a SWAP macro that will swap bytes within short. Is this the right approach?

**code I have added after above:(to make it work on LITTLE as well)**

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER != __BIG_ENDIAN

*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[0] = SWAP(*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[0]);
*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[2] = SWAP(*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[2]);
*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[4] = SWAP(*(unsigned short *)&mac_addr[4]);

#endif
```

Comment: msg->Mac is char Mac[16+1]

Comment: Why do you SWAP? Why do you print directly, why don't you print ntoh(new_mac[..])?

Comment: @WernerHenze you mean I should just again do ntoh for LITTLE ?

Comment: Yes. sscanf reads and stores host Byte order, then you hton for Network Byte order, then you print that out. So if your host Byte order is the same as Network Byte order, you print out what you entered. If host Byte order is not the Network Byte order, then you print out swapped Bytes. The solution is not to swap but to ntohs before printing. Please tell me if this answers your question (which is not totally clear to me), then I can write it as an answer that you could accept.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test on little endian machine ? Since hton already takes into account the arch byteness :

```
/* Copyright (C) 1993-2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#undef  htonl
#undef  ntohl

uint32_t
htonl (uint32_t x)
{
#if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
  return x;
#elif BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
  return __bswap_32 (x);
#else
# error "What kind of system is this?"
#endif
}
weak_alias (htonl, ntohl)
```

Comment: yes it doesn't work on LITTLE Endian. A mac "0000.a123.ac12" get printed as 0000.ffffff23ffffffa1.12ac

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for MAC addresses: they should be treated as an array of 6 bytes, so there should be no endianess problem.  Trying to map other types (for efficiency?) is just asking for trouble.

So scanf should be:

```
sscanf(msg->Mac, "%2hhx%2hhx.%2hhx%2hhx.%2hhx%2hhx", 
              &new_mac[0], &new_mac[1],
              &new_mac[2], &new_mac[3],
              &new_mac[4], &new_mac[5])
```

Comment: I know that would have been the best way. But I am working on legacy code and can not make that change now in later code. new_mac gets accessed in multiple places.

Comment: So doing this here will crop problem somewhere else in the code.